# Chat vertical window mode − hide the entire sidebar when window gets narrow

Tags: script, chat

If you're trying to chat in a very narrow window, you probably don't need the sidebar anyway. And toggling that script every time is inconvenient. Now you can install this style:

```
@media screen and (max-width:900px){ #sidebar {display:none} #main {width:unset} }
```

Change the desired max width at which the sidebar is still visible to what you need. For example, if you are using FULL HD resolution (1920x1080) and you only want this mode to kick in when you put 3 chat windows side by side (right-click on taskbar > Show windows side by side), then 1920/3=640px.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Geshode no question here :p This is a weird site which isn't like others where you ask questions and expect answers. It's basically script/extension requests or postings. Technically, this here would be an example of a self-answered question, which is permitted to be posted in just the question on this site.